# Should I split up my XStream converter per class?

Tags: java, converters, xstream

I am working on a program that uses XStream to write out to XML. As it stands I have only one class that implements Converter. This single converter takes in my ENTIRE configuration which is a HashMap at its root and the value of each key is an new instance of `VMwareServer` class which in turn has a HashMap where the value of key is a new instance of `VMwareVirtualMachine` class. Each of the respective classes have methods for setting and getting things like `IP address` and `port number`.

What I am wondering is if this is proper way to implement the XStream converter, or should I create a separate converter to convert each class to XML on it own?

I can show some code if there is still questions about what I mean.

Comment: What are you doing in the converter? Xstream can deep marshall any object without any converter.

Comment: Mainly I am using the converter to reformat the output into a little more "pretty" form. The reason I am using the converter is some of objects from java are moved around to make things organized.

Comment: You should have converter per class.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat debatable, but I would argue for having a separate converter for each class. This has several benefits: if you later need to return a subset of your complete view, you will be able to easily decompose the structure along class-based lines (perhaps, for example, to limit information by permissions).  If you need to return slightly different representations in different contexts, you can do so on a class-by-class basis rather than duplicating all of the presentational logic in your monolithic class.

Comment: Yeah see that is what I was kinda thinking. There are some cases where depending on certain values I don't end up generating certain parts of the XML file.